# About push notification service in iphone

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I went through the Apple api documentation related to Push notification service in iPhone and all the possible links I found through the google. So I've created the SSL certificate and have got a device token.

But after that, how to use this push notification service in an iPhone application?. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Is the problem how to use/code up local push notifications or how to setup a server to do push notifications ?

Answer (score 1):

For server/remote push notifications - depends on what you plan to run on your server or if you are going to use a third party service to do it.

Here are [some notes](http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2011/05/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-rails-with-redis-and-apn_sender/) if you have your own Rails based server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thirty push services like [PushBots](https://pushbots.com/)